# Fonts Folder in Symfony2 no load Fonts

Tags: php, html, css, symfony, fonts

i have a problem with font-awesome.min.css in Symfony2,it doesn't find font file. 
Here my path: symfony_path/src/Acme/Exbundle/Resources/views/public/fonts/.
the url in css src:

```
url('../../Resources/public/fonts/fontawesome-webfont.eot?v=4.0.3');.
```

i run this commands:

```
php app/console assets:install web --symlink php app/console assetic:dump
```

but the fonts doesn't work(fonts doesn't appear)!!!
is there anyone who has had the same problem?
p.s: i call css like this

```
 `{% stylesheets '@Bundle/Resources/public/css/font-awesome.min.css' filter='yui_css'%}`           

<link href="{{ asset_url }}" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet"/> 

{% endstylesheets %}
```

Comment: When you call "php app/console assets:install web --symlink", your public folders are dumped/symlinked into "web/bundles/someyourbundlename"

Comment: Your base web path is `web`. You cannot access any parent folders of the `web` one through URL

Comment: @Touki how i can access it?

Comment: @willy Use `url(../fonts/)`

Comment: @willy *"No work"* isn't an error... Did you see what URL is generated? What files did your browser tried to get? `http://site.devel/app_dev.php/fonts/fontawesome-webfont.eot`? You didn't put just `url(../fonts/)` but `url(../fonts/fontawesome-webfont.eot)` did you ?

Comment: @Touki i put this url('../fonts/fontawesome-webfont.eot?v=4.0.3') and i browser it(firebug), but http://site.devel/app_dev.php/fonts/fontawesome-webfont.eot gives 404